# Why Broadcast Receivers are not working in android 8.1?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I tried broadcast receiver in my app. It's working fine in android 7.1 but it won't work in android 8.1. What can I do?

```
<!-- Manifest Code -->

    <receiver
        android:name=".Receiver_PhoneCall"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Please write at least part of your code in order to investigate

Comment: @MohamadArmoon I have added my manifest code

Comment: Do you have the relevant permissions? Also, you should remove the `<category>` tag inside `<intent-filter>` because broadcast `Intent`s do not use that.

Comment: do you have permission PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS?